# Keep screen state after navigating

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I have a navigator looking like this :

```
<NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Support" component={SupportScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
 </NavigationContainer>
```

HomeScreen and SupportScreen both only have a  component rendered in their function.
I want every screen to persist the content but it is not working for me
here are the steps :

1. the navigator loads on the Home screen
2. I type 'abc' in Home's TextInput
3. navigate to SupportScreen
4. Type 'xyz' in Support's TextInput
5. goBack/navigate to Home
6. I can see 'abc' in the input
7. navigate to Support
8. the input is empty

I would expect Support's TextInput to keep the text in the input

If I swap `<Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />` and `<Stack.Screen name="Support" component={SupportScreen} />`, then the same exact situation occurs but Home looses his text and Support not, so I think this behaviour is related to the inital screen or something like this...

Here is a [Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@devcashback/how-to-keep-screen-state-after-navigating)

Can you explain to me this behaviour and and how to make it work as I expected ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 4 actions you need to know in React Navigation.

push(), navigate(), goBack(), pop()

The first time only initial screen will be placed in the navigation screen.

'push' will add another new screen on the top of navigation stack regardless the same screen exists in the stack.

'navigate' will switch to the screen in the stack if the same screen exists in the navigation stack or it will work like 'push'.

'goBack' is like a reverse action of 'navigate' and 'pop' is a reverse action of 'push'. 'pop' is to remove the current active screen in the stack simply. 'goBack' works either like 'navigate' if the current screen was activated by 'navigate' action and like 'pop' if the current screen was activated by 'push' action.

When the screen is removed out of the navigation stack by 'goBack' or 'pop' action it means the screen will be unmounted and all data in the component will be lost.

In your case 'Support' screen got removed because you have got navigation back to 'Home' screen in the stack. When you tried to navigate to 'Support' screen again it's components get initialized. If you only switch between 'Home' and 'Support' screen without 'pop' you can keep the previous component status on 'Support' screen.

---

Updated:

With Stack navigation all screens except 'initial screen' are unmounted when navigate to other screen.
By trick, you can use Tab navigation with height 0 tabbar to keep the screen's state but you should do something more to make header like stack navigation.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';


function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>HomeScreen</Text>
      <TextInput/>
      <Button
        title="Support ->"
        onPress={() =>
          navigation.navigate('Support')
        }
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function SupportScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [txt, setText] = useState('')
  useEffect(()=>{
    return ()=>{
      console.log('SupportScreen unmounted')
    }
  }, [])
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>SupportScreen</Text>
      <TextInput value={txt} onChangeText={setText}/>
      <Button
        title="<- Home"
        onPress={() =>
          navigation.navigate('Home')
        }
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
       tabBarOptions={{
         style: {height: 0}
       }}
      >
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Support" component={SupportScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, what do you mean by "switch between 'Home' and 'Support' screen without 'pop' " ?
How do I do this programmatically ?

Comment: By calling 'navigate' function. The first time it will push the screen in the stack because there is not the screen in the stack but if the screen already exists in the stack, it will just activate it (move to the top of the stack). If you don't 'goBack' from the 'Support' screen at 5 step in your example and just navigate to 'Home' screen 'Support' screen will be not removed in the stack and keep the component status.

Comment: I am already using navigate, you can see my code here : https://snack.expo.dev/@devcashback/how-to-keep-screen-state-after-navigating